# Hive: Unable to access database

Tags: hadoop, hive, solaris, cloudera-cdh

I find myself in a bit of a 'hive' pickle here. On booting the Hive CLI from my home directory, I can access the 'fooDB' database, which I had created earlier:

```
hadoop@server-7:~$ hive
/usr/local/hive/hive-1.1.0-cdh5.5.2/bin/hive: line 258: no: command not found

WARNING: Hive CLI is deprecated and migration to Beeline is recommended.
hive> SHOW DATABASES;
OK
default
fooDB
Time taken: 0.717 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

But when I try to boot it from any other location in my file-system, I am unable to access 'fooDB':

```
hadoop@server-7:~/Downloads$ hive
/usr/local/hive/hive-1.1.0-cdh5.5.2/bin/hive: line 258: no: command not found

WARNING: Hive CLI is deprecated and migration to Beeline is recommended.
hive> SHOW DATABASES;
OK
default
Time taken: 0.72 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Basically, the objects created after starting the Hive CLI from one particular location in the file-system, let's say '/home/hadoop/dir1', is not accessible from any other location in the file-system via. the Hive CLI and vice-versa.

The relevant-hive section from my .bashrc looks like this:

```
## HIVE VARIABLES ##
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive/hive-1.1.0-cdh5.5.2
export HIVE_CONF_DIR=$HIVE_HOME/conf
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
```

So I am not really sure how to proceed here. I also tried using an alias for hive, which did not help. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After scouring the web, I finally bumped into [this](http://www.hiregion.com/2010/01/hive-metastore-derby-db.html)
which was exactly what I was looking for.

Hope this helps out people coming across the above problem!